# Automatically fall back to "IN MEMORY CACHE" if my Memcached servers go offline

Tags: memcached, servicestack

This is more of a general advice question. We have ServiceStack.Caching.Memcached running in our service stack application.

It works great but I am wondering what best practice is with regard to memcached failing?

ie.. Should we make our application fall back, automatically, to use **in memory cache** if memcached falls over?

OR, is this something we should not worry about as we will have more than 1 memcached server so the likelihood of both falling over is minimal.

thanks in advance

Russ

Comment: There's no right answer here, it is going to depend on your specific service and the users. Will the cache going down make the system too slow to get work done on? Then you need a backup. Will users be able to get along just fine without it? Then skip it.

Comment: Hi RuSs, have you come up with anything useful? Thanks.